# couchbase upsert/insert silently failing with ttl

Tags: insert, couchbase, upsert

i am trying to upsert 10 documents using spring boot. It is failing to upsert "few documents" with TTL.There is no error or exception. If i do not provide ttl then it is working as expected.

In addition to that, if i increase the ttl to a different value then also all the documents are getting created.

On the other hand, if i reduce the ttl then failing to insert few more docuemnts.

I tried to insert the failed document(single document out of 10) from another poc with the same ttl the document is getting created.

```
public Flux<JsonDocument> upsertAll(final List<JsonDocument> jsonDocuments) {

        return Flux
            .from(keys())
            .flatMap(key -> Flux
                .fromIterable(jsonDocuments)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .flatMap(jsonDocument -> {
                    final String arg = String.format("upsertAll-%s", jsonDocument);

                    return Mono
                        .just(asyncBucket
                            .upsert(jsonDocument, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .doOnError(error -> log.error(jsonDocument.content(), error, "failed to upsert")))

                        .map(obs -> Tuples.of(obs, jsonDocument.content()))
                        .map(tuple2 -> log.observableHandler(tuple2))
                        .map(observable1 -> Tuples.of(observable1, jsonDocument.content()))
                        .flatMap(tuple2 -> log.monoHandler(tuple2))
                        ;
                })
                .sequential())
            ;
    }
```

```
List<JsonDocument> jsonDocuments = new LinkedList<>();
dbService.upsertAll(jsonDocuments)
            .subscribe();
```

some one please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which Spring Data version are you using? What is the size of the database? Are you running it locally? How much memory is allocated to the bucket? Hard to guess the problem, but at first, seems to be a problem with the network or the resources allocated to couchbase.

Comment: Hi Srivi, Can you show some code please, especially the part where you are setting the TTL?

Comment: i am running from local. bucket size is 10gb out of which 100mb is used. if it is a network issue how it is working with a different bucket?

Comment: i am using asyncBucket.upsert(document, timeout, timeUnit) and setting the ttl like below JsonDocument.create(sampleDTO.getId(), ttl, JsonObject.fromJson(jsonString)). reading this ttl value from yml.

Comment: @deniswsrosa i added some code snippet. please take look and help me with your thoughts.

Comment: What version of the Couchbase Java SDK are you using? Are the TTL values greater or less than 30 days? I'm wondering if you could be running into [JCBC-1645](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JCBC-1645).

Comment: @dnault i am using couchbase SDK 2.7.15 and ttl is 20 mins if i give 30 mins it is creating the document. if i change the id for that document  it is getting created with 20 mins ttl.

Answer (score 1):

Due to an oddity in the Couchbase server API, TTL values less than 30 days are treated differently than values greater than 30 days.

In order to get consistent behavior with Couchbase Java SDK 2.x, you'll need to adjust the TTL value before passing it to the SDK:

```
// adjust TTL for Couchbase Java SDK 2.x
public static int adjustTtl(int ttlSeconds) {
  return ttlSeconds < TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(30)
      ? ttlSeconds
      : (int) (ttlSeconds + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
}
```

In Couchbase Java SDK 3.0.6 this is no longer required; just pass a Duration and the SDK will adjust the value behind the scenes if necessary.

Comment: I tried to adjust the ttl but no difference in the behaviour.If I change the document id or ttl it is getting inserted. Will there be any cache related issues?.

Comment: any other thoughts on this?